# How can I vlookup two files with the help of Google Bigquery and Google Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata, google-cloud-storage, vlookup

I need your support to vlookup a column from a file to my BigQuery spreadsheet.

Currently I have a project.dataset.spreadsheet in Google BigQuery with several columns including one with the field name "query". 
And I have another spreadsheet as an xlsx file inside my Google Cloud Storage that has the columns "query" and "group".

I would like to add the right "group" value from this file field to my BigQuery spreadsheet.

Thanks in advance and cheers from Austria!

Nes

Answer (score 0):

The that I will address the problem is to transform the xlsx file to CSV, load it into bigquery and perform a join with your existing data into bigquery.

If you need a new table, perform an insert select into a new table, else a view could be enough.

However, my answer is maybe incomplete. Depends on the need of repeat or not the process with your xlsx file and other details that you might not describe.

Cheers from vienne (but in France !)